Extent ceph storage volume size
have installed ceph storage clustering on three nodes that first node is bootstrap. also i created a pool and then a created volume with 20GB size and then a linux client added to this network that can using this volume successfully. now how i can resize and extend this volume size that now is 20GB? i used ceph web panel https://Ceph:8443 and then increase volume size to 30Gb when in the web panel new size will be displayed and also in the command line with this command rbd ls --pool bdpooltest -l we can new size of volume. but in the client system when i execute this command df -h i get old size of volume. how i can fix this problem?
please help me for solving this problem.

It depends how you are using the RBD image in Linux, but in short you need to make Linux aware of the size change, for example:
echo 1 > /sys/class/block/<device>/device/rescan

Once Linux is aware of the new size you can resize the filesystem, example:
resize2fs /dev/rbd0

or
xfs_growfs /mnt/data

It all depends how you have mounted the RBD image, so execute these commands with care!
